# Kendo UI Grid settings

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is my grid settings:

```
 $scope.documentSources = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                fun: console.log("Read"),
                url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
                }
            },
            update: {
                fun: console.log("Update"),
                url: serviceBase + "Documents/GetListDocuments",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
                }
            },
            save: {
                fun: console.log("Create"),
                url: serviceBase + "Documents/SetDocument",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: 'hello hello',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authGlobalService.getAuthorizationData().token);
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                if (options.filter) {
                    options.filter = options.filter.filters;
                }

                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "dateAdded",
            dir: "desc"
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true
});

$scope.msg = false;

$scope.documentListGridOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.documentSources,
    selectable: 'row',
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    pageable: true,
    change: function (idSelectedVote) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.setSelected(idSelectedVote.sender.dataItem(idSelectedVote.sender.select()));
        });
    },
    dataValueField: "id",
    columns: [{
        title: "Id dokumentu",
        field: "documentid",
        hidden: true
    }, {
        title: "Nazwa dokumentu",
        field: "nameDocument",
    }, {
        title: "Opis",
        field: "descriptionDocument",
    }, {
        title: "Data dodania",
        field: "dateAdded",
        template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(dateAdded, ''), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm') #"

    }, {
        title: "Nazwa Pliku",
        field: "fileName"
    }]
};
```

And I have a problem because counting rows doesn't work and neither the page  because I have always one row. Like on my ss below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56M7j.png

Can you help me with this? It's probably something wrong with my grid settings.

Comment: does your json from rest service have this kind of return `{ data : [], total : 10 }` ?

Comment: No, only 1 this is maybe a problem.

Comment: Well yeah , the problem is the datasource expecting data array and total for showing 1 of total on the bottom of the grid.